# Dynamic Sub Aggregations using Nest

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I want to dynamically create sub aggregations on Nest search query from a List or Dictionary. Below is the working code which was written on compile time itself. In the
below example the date would be first aggregated by field MonthandYear and
then followed by sub aggregations on two other fields dimensionname and
measurename.

Now consider i have to write this query on run time. I will get the three
(may be more or less) fields in a list or string[] or querystring and i
have to form the same aggregation query on run time.I used
termsaggregationcontainer object to build my aggregation but i am not able
to append aggregations to existing fields on a loop.

Please let me know if i am still unclear. I will try to write some sample
code that i tried earlier.

```
client.Search<object>(s => s
                  .Index("masterdata")
                  .Type("masterdatatype")                  
                  .Aggregations(agr => agr.Terms("Date", tr => tr.Field("MonthandYear").Size(int.MaxValue).Order(TermsOrder.TermAscending)
                  .Aggregations(a => a.Terms("DimensionValue", te => te.Field(dimensionName ).Size(int.MaxValue)
                   .Aggregations(ag => ag.Sum("SumofMeasure", t => t.Field(measureName)))))))                  
                  .Query(a => a.Terms(t => t.Field(filterName).Terms(filterValues)))
);
```

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to be able to provide an answer. what do the list or dictionary contain? What types of aggregation do you need to build? If you could edit your question to provide more detail, I may be able to help. Also check out https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-aggregations.html It may give you some ideas

Comment: The list will contain the fields on which we need to do sub aggregations. From the above code, the list will contain "MonthandYear","dimensionName","measureName" and i need to form a sub aggregation query using the fields in this list

Comment: Please edit your question to include additional detail and code that could help answer it